# Write a differential equation for this description

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm still very new to differential equations and not sure if I'm understanding this question correctly:

> If the velocity at time $t$ for a particle moving along a straight line
>   is proportional to the fourth power of its position $x$, write a
>   differential equation that fits this description.

So I think the equation would be:

$\frac{dt}{dx}=tx^4$

Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite. dx/dt = k x^4, where k is the proportionality constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. This is what you want:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}(t)=\alpha x(t)^{4}\text{ where }\alpha\text{ is a constant}.
$$
$x(t)$ is the position of the particle at time $t$, from which it
follows that $\frac{dx}{dt}(t)$ is its velocity at time $t$. $\alpha$
appears in the above since the question asks the velocity to be proportional
to $x(t)^{4}$.

Comment: For the most part I can follow your logic, however, I'm confused by $\frac{dx}{dt}(t)$; are we multiplying $t$ by the derivative of $x(t)$?

Comment: $dx/dt$ is a function of time (the velocity is not constant with respect to time). $t$ appearing in the brackets is not multiplication, but an input to the function.

Comment: Ahh ok, I just have never seen it notated that way.  I understand

Comment: So for example, if $y=x(t)$ then this could be rewritten as $y'=ay^4$

Comment: Yes. It's better to be explicit when you are learning (e.g. writing $(t)$). There will be plenty of time to hide notation when you are more experienced.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!